# Pass fastify instance to controllers at a top level

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

Rather than passing the `fastify instance` to every function, how can I pass it at a top level only once so its available to all functions in the controller?

```js
// route file
import { FastifyPluginAsync } from 'fastify'

import RootController from '../root.controller'

const root: FastifyPluginAsync = async (fastify, opts): Promise<void> => {
  fastify.get('/', RootController.index(fastify))
  fastify.get('/show', RootController.show(fastify))
}

export default root
```

```js
// controller file
import { FastifyInstance, FastifyRequest, FastifyReply } from 'fastify'

export default {
  index: (fastify: FastifyInstance) => async (request: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply) => {
    const hugs = fastify.someSupport()

    reply.send({ status: 'ok', love: hugs })
  },

  show: (fastify: FastifyInstance) => async (request: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply) => {
    const hugs = 'extra ' + fastify.someSupport()

    reply.send({ status: 'ok', love: hugs })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a simple, mechanical refactoring using closures:

```js
// controller file
import { FastifyInstance, FastifyRequest, FastifyReply } from 'fastify'

export default async function installRootController(fastify: FastifyInstance, opts): Promise<void> {
  fastify.get('/', async (request: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply) => {
    const hugs = fastify.someSupport()

    reply.send({ status: 'ok', love: hugs })
  });

  fastify.get('/show', async (request: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply) => {
    const hugs = 'extra ' + fastify.someSupport()

    reply.send({ status: 'ok', love: hugs })
  });
};
```

The inner functions (the async handlers for `/` and `/show`) have access to `fastify` because it's accessible from lexical scope of the surrounding function. This enables you to encapsulate entire "controllers" as Fastify plugins, ready to install like so:

```js
fastify.register(installRootController);
```

Note that the "routes" file now has no use.

Comment: Thanks Rob that's certainly an approach I didn't consider. I am currently using the https://github.com/fastify/fastify-autoload to load all routes in that folder as it gives some additional benefits. If I still want to use the `autoload plugin` is there another way apart from your answer to achieve that?

Comment: Not sure, but I think fastify-autoload's docs imply that you can export a full plugin and it should get the fastify instance as an argument - see the snippet in the README after the `options` section. Looks exactly like the refactored function export to me!

Comment: Yeh its the same as what you wrote... I guess what I'm trying to do is move the logic from the route closure into the controller to keep the routes clean.

Comment: You could always turn the controller into a class, and pass the fastify instance using dependency injection. I would not worry too much, though - after all, the Controller here is a "pure fabrication" and does not represent a real-life concept. It exists only as a route-grouping facility, a role which the closure fulfills just as well.

Comment: Agreed Rob... I did use a class at one point but didn't seem elegant. Coming from strong PHP (laravel) background I need to think differently now I guess. Thanks for you time and effort.